# What is the maximum number of lines a TextArea control can hold?

Tags: apache-flex, user-controls

I have an app that has text appended to a TextArea (TA). It automatically scrolls to keep the recent line added in view. Over time, this could be a lot. Do I have to worry about this? Is there an upper limit? And, if so, how can I prune the oldest lines of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in the documentation, but if it gets too big you could run into memory issues. But we're talking collosal here.

It's easy enough to remove oldest lines using the slice() method